# Validar la "e" en inputs con Js

Tags: javascript, numberformat, validate

Lo que quiero hacer se que es sencillo, pero no encuentro cual es el codigo para poder validar...

Basicamente, lo que quiero es validar que mi input sea **numerico** y que al mismo tiempo no acepte la **e** como si fuese un numero...

Esto se que se puede hacer con Js hace un tiempo ya lo habia hecho, pero no tengo idea como, quizas con una expresion regular pero no recuerdo como hacerla.

Comment: Acabo de responder algo similar https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/561179/301324

Comment: En la respuesta que pones aun púedo escribir la **e** solo que luego de eso, ya solo me deja escribir un número más y se detiene. Yo lo que quiero es que no se pueda escribir la **e** o que almenos saber si se escribió

Comment: Si el input lo tienes en un formulario normal (no ajax) ponle el `type="number"` y que escriban lo que quieran que cuando intenten hacer el submit no les dejará, si no es un número, por la validación interna que hace el propio navegador al interpretar ese type.

Comment: ¿Y si tratas el valor primero como una cadena? Así te es fácil mirar si tiene la `e` o no, impedir caracteres distintos de dígitos,... lo que quieras. Sobre usar una expresión regular, aqui tienes una ayuda: https://altruistas.org/determinar-si-una-cadena-alfanumerica-es-un-numero-en-javascript/

Comment: @masterguru, un `input` de tipo `number` admite valores como `1e23`. Lo que el OP quiere es evitar la introducción de caracteres no numéricos. Aunque `1e23` es un valor numérico válido, al parecer el OP simplemente quiere evitar que se introduzca nada diferente de números.

Comment: @MauricioContreras No lo sabia, gracias por la información. Entonces quizás usando un input tipo **text** con un `pattern="[0-9]*"` adecuado podría hacer el mismo efecto que estaba sugiriendo antes, es decir, que al someter el formulario no lo permitiera si el pattern no se cumple.